Is it possible to configure Ethertype DSA VLAN tagging on an Ethernet port that has a real PHY connection to the outside world?
I am working on an embedded system that will connect a processor running Linux to an Ethernet switch via a "conduit" Ethernet link (e.g. eth0) using the port-based Ethertype DSA (Marvell) frame tagging protocol, so that the Linux kernel will present the userspace with separate Ethernet links for each of the switch's user ports (e.g. lan1, lan2, lan3).
As I understand it this is usually done via a fixed phy-less conduit (e.g. xMII) and an MDIO link between the processor and the switch so that the processor can configure and control the physical user ports.
I want to do some software development ahead of receiving the hardware, so I want to "fake" the MDIO link, or in some other way configure the kernel, such that it uses port-based EDSA frame tagging over an ordinary (PHY-equipped) Ethernet port, resulting in a frame layout like this:
         7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0  
       .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
     0 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
       |   Ether Destination Address   |
    +6 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
       |     Ether Source Address      |
    +6 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+  --
       |  Prog. DSA Ether Type [15:8]  |  |
    +1 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+  |
       |  Prog. DSA Ether Type [7:0]   |  | EDSA tag
    +1 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+  |
       |     Reserved (0x00 0x00)      |  |
    +2 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+  |  --
       | Mode  |b29|   Switch Device   |  |  |
    +1 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+  |  |
       |    Switch Port    |b18|b17|b16|  |  |
    +1 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+  |  | DSA tag
       | PRI [2:0] |b12|  VID [11:8]   |  |  |
    +1 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+  |  |
       |           VID [7:0]           |  |  |
    +1 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+  -- --
       |       Ether Length/Type       |
    +2 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
       .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .

...where Switch Port corresponds to the switch's user port number.
The documentation of kernel modules dsa_loop and dsa_loop_bdinfo imply that these might be suitable, and the source code seems to link .netdev  = "eth0" to some user ports ("lan1".."lan4") but even though I can modprobe dsa_loop into my kernel I don't see any virtual port devices created by the kernel (I am using ifconfig -a to show net devices).
    ~# lsmod
    Module                  Size  Used by
    dsa_loop               16384  0
    dsa_core              118784  1 dsa_loop

When doing the modprobe dsa_loop I see a call to dsa_loop_init but no call to dsa_loop_drv_probe.
So I guess I have several questions:

Are the dsa_loop and dsa_loop_init modules intended to allow EDSA tagging to be performed on a "normal" Ethernet link?
How are these modules intended to be used?
Are there any other ways of configuring Linux to do this without access to the switch MDIO?


OP said:

Are the dsa_loop and dsa_loop_init modules intended to allow EDSA tagging to be performed on a "normal" Ethernet link?

Yes.
The problem I was running into is the result of an ordering problem between these loadable modules and the fixed-phy layer code which was being compiled as a built-in module.
When the kernel configuration was changed to compile them as build-in modules along with the fixed-phy code the problem went away and I could see calls to dsa_loop_drv_probe.
